# Must Declare the scalar variable error in Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_GetLatestMmdData]

AS
DECLARE
     @vReturnVar VARCHAR(10) 
    ,@vRCount VARCHAR(10)
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;
SET @vRCount =(SELECT Distinct Shift From [dbo].[tblMMDLogEntry] Where Shift Like 'Night     ' And Date=(SELECT  MAX(Date)  
                FROM [dbo].[tblMMDLogEntry]))
IF(@vRCount>0) 
BEGIN
    SET @vReturnVar='Night      '
END
Else
BEGIN
    SET @vReturnVar='Evening    '
END             

SELECT
    convert(varchar,[Date],103) Date
                    ,Shift
                    ,SlNo
                    ,TotalManpower
                    ,JobDescription
                    ,PermitNo
                    ,StartTime
                    ,EndTime
                    ,AllotedManpower
                    ,Supervisior
                    ,AShift
                    ,GShift
                    ,BShift
                    ,CShift
                    ,Remarks 
    FROM [dbo].[tblMMDLogEntry] WHERE Date=(SELECT  MAX(Date)  
     FROM [dbo].[tblMMDLogEntry]) 
     AND Shift= @vReturnVar 

END
```

I have the Following Code in My stored Procedure. i have already declared that @vReturnVar
but still showing 'Must Declare the scalar variable "@vReturnVar".

Comment: What line is your error coming from? Could the variable be out of scope at that point?

Comment: Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 19
Must declare the scalar variable "@vReturnVar".

Comment: I am Just Trying to Run the main Select query to check the result. but the following error is shown.

Comment: If you are just selecting and executing the SELECT query then it has no concept of the variable. The variable must be part of the SQL you are executing. Copy and paste that section into the beginning of your query that you are trying to run.

Comment: Edit the question to show exactly the portion of code you are executing. The answer below should definitely solve your problem. (basically for the code above, delete `ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_GetLatestMmdData] AS`, the first `begin` and the final `end` and it should run )

Comment: Ohh ! Yes You are Right. But How Can i Run the last Select Query to Check My Result with the following Declared Variables ?

Comment: Ok Sure ! i am trying !

Comment: You almost certainly want to look at JBrook's answer below too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't it include a "COUNT()"

```
        SET @vRCount =(SELECT COUNT(Distinct Shift) 
                       From [dbo].[tblMMDLogEntry] 
                       Where Shift Like 'Night     ' And Date=(SELECT  MAX(Date)  
                       FROM [dbo].[tblMMDLogEntry]))
```

Comment: Yes @Jbooks ! i had corrected that error ! that was a mistake .

Answer (score 1):

Put

```
DECLARE
@vReturnVar VARCHAR(10) 
,@vRCount VARCHAR(10)
```

After the `BEGIN` of the stored procedure

Comment: Did that but Still Same Problem . I cant understand why is this happening .

Answer (score 0):

declare after begin
DECLARE @vReturnVar VARCHAR(10)

surely works for you